# Bulk sms to a smart group in civi 4.4?

Tags: smartgroups, sms

I want to send out a bulk sms asking for evaluation of our event, to the participant of the event, the day after the event.

I then thought of creating a smart group of those contact with the participant status 'attended' to my event. And then schedule a bulk sms to that smart group.

But it doesn't seem possible to send bulk sms to a smart group.

Is it possible to send bulk sms to a smart group? And if so, how to do that?

(Drupal and CiviCRM 4.4)

Comment: naive question, but since you didn't specify this, can you pls confirm that Bulk SMS work for Standard Groups on your site.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of CiviCRM you are on.

I am sure you can do this with scheduled reminders in 4.6 or 4.7 provided you have an SMS gateway configured. See http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/sms-text-messaging/set-up/  and http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/scheduled-reminders/

You won't need a smart group as once you have selected the event you can specify which participant statuses are sent the SMS.

Comment: I am on 4.4. I need to send the sms at a specific time, so that everyone gets it at the same time